# Form post never executes action and has a memory bug in MVC 6 RC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, memory-leaks, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-rc2

I've encountered some weird behaviour after MVC 6 RC1 to RC2 migration.

Let's say we have a dumbed down version of a form that will POST to an action upon submit:

```
@model InstitutionViewModel
<form asp-controller="Institution" asp-action="Create" method="post">
   @Html.Hidden("companyId", ViewBag.CompanyId)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.LocationId, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Locations, new { Class = "form-control" })
   @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { Class = "form-control" })
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

And then we have this InstitutionViewModel

```
public class InstitutionViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public int LocationId { get; set; }
   public LocationViewModel Location { get; set; }
}
```

And the action we are POSTing to, looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(int companyId, InstitutionViewModel institution)
{
   ...
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the submit never triggers the action. The browser is showing the spinner and something is happening in the background, but the program never arrives at the action. Even worse - when this happens the **RAM consumption of the dotnet process starts gradually rising** until it just runs out of it. The last time I let the website run in this state, the dotnet process was using 7GB of RAM and it only took about 2 or 3 minutes to get to that point!
[image]

This used to work without any problem in RC1. The only solution I have found for this so far is to remove the LocationViewModel property from InstitutionViewModel. If I do that, the POST reaches the action without any problems.

The LocationViewModel does not seem the be the problem by itself either, because the same happens if there is any other viewModel in the class as a property, regardless of what the viewModel contains.

Now I'm confused weather this is a bug in RC2 or I'm doing something horribly wrong. Maybe I forgot to include something or I broke something in Startup.cs and project.json while upgrading to RC2. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: How do you know it never reaches the action? Looks like the client is issuing many requests that get stuck on the server at the same time.

Comment: Pause the debugger while this is happening. What is going on?

Comment: Well I am using the debugger and it never gets to the first line of the action. And even if I run it in release without any debug points it does the same. If I inspect in Chrome the network tag also shows that there was only one request sent.

Comment: What happened when you paused the debugger while this was happening?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm currently away from the computer with the code. I'll report back on monday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I'm confused weather this is a bug in RC2 or I'm doing something horribly wrong.

It's [a known bug in ASP.NET Core MVC RC2](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4666), caused by an incorrect handling of deeply nested models in the default model binder factory.

The recommended workaround is [to use a custom binder factory until it is fixed](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4666#issuecomment-220156872):

```
public class MyModelBinderFactory : IModelBinderFactory
{
    private readonly IModelMetadataProvider _metadataProvider;
    private readonly IModelBinderProvider[] _providers;

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, IModelBinder> _cache;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new <see cref="ModelBinderFactory"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="metadataProvider">The <see cref="IModelMetadataProvider"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="options">The <see cref="IOptions{TOptions}"/> for <see cref="MvcOptions"/>.</param>
    public MyModelBinderFactory(IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, IOptions<MvcOptions> options)
    {
        _metadataProvider = metadataProvider;
        _providers = options.Value.ModelBinderProviders.ToArray();

        _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, IModelBinder>();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IModelBinder CreateBinder(ModelBinderFactoryContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        // We perform caching in CreateBinder (not in CreateBinderCore) because we only want to
        // cache the top-level binder.
        IModelBinder binder;
        if (context.CacheToken != null && _cache.TryGetValue(context.CacheToken, out binder))
        {
            return binder;
        }

        var providerContext = new DefaultModelBinderProviderContext(this, context);
        binder = CreateBinderCore(providerContext, context.CacheToken);
        if (binder == null)
        {
            var message = $"Could not create model binder for {providerContext.Metadata.ModelType}.";
            throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
        }

        if (context.CacheToken != null)
        {
            _cache.TryAdd(context.CacheToken, binder);
        }

        return binder;
    }

    private IModelBinder CreateBinderCore(DefaultModelBinderProviderContext providerContext, object token)
    {
        if (!providerContext.Metadata.IsBindingAllowed)
        {
            return NoOpBinder.Instance;
        }

        // A non-null token will usually be passed in at the the top level (ParameterDescriptor likely).
        // This prevents us from treating a parameter the same as a collection-element - which could
        // happen looking at just model metadata.
        var key = new Key(providerContext.Metadata, token);

        // If we're currently recursively building a binder for this type, just return
        // a PlaceholderBinder. We'll fix it up later to point to the 'real' binder
        // when the stack unwinds.
        var collection = providerContext.Collection;

        IModelBinder binder;
        if (collection.TryGetValue(key, out binder))
        {
            if (binder != null)
            {
                return binder;
            }

            // Recursion detected, create a DelegatingBinder.
            binder = new PlaceholderBinder();
            collection[key] = binder;
            return binder;
        }

        // OK this isn't a recursive case (yet) so "push" an entry on the stack and then ask the providers
        // to create the binder.
        collection.Add(key, null);

        IModelBinder result = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < _providers.Length; i++)
        {
            var provider = _providers[i];
            result = provider.GetBinder(providerContext);
            if (result != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (result == null && token == null)
        {
            // Use a no-op binder if we're below the top level. At the top level, we throw.
            result = NoOpBinder.Instance;
        }

        // If the DelegatingBinder was created, then it means we recursed. Hook it up to the 'real' binder.
        var delegatingBinder = collection[key] as PlaceholderBinder;
        if (delegatingBinder != null)
        {
            delegatingBinder.Inner = result;
        }

        collection[key] = result;
        return result;
    }

    private class DefaultModelBinderProviderContext : ModelBinderProviderContext
    {
        private readonly MyModelBinderFactory _factory;

        public DefaultModelBinderProviderContext(
            MyModelBinderFactory factory,
            ModelBinderFactoryContext factoryContext)
        {
            _factory = factory;
            Metadata = factoryContext.Metadata;
            BindingInfo = factoryContext.BindingInfo;

            MetadataProvider = _factory._metadataProvider;
            Collection = new Dictionary<Key, IModelBinder>();
        }

        private DefaultModelBinderProviderContext(
            DefaultModelBinderProviderContext parent,
            ModelMetadata metadata)
        {
            Metadata = metadata;

            _factory = parent._factory;
            MetadataProvider = parent.MetadataProvider;
            Collection = parent.Collection;

            BindingInfo = new BindingInfo()
            {
                BinderModelName = metadata.BinderModelName,
                BinderType = metadata.BinderType,
                BindingSource = metadata.BindingSource,
                PropertyFilterProvider = metadata.PropertyFilterProvider,
            };
        }

        public override BindingInfo BindingInfo { get; }

        public override ModelMetadata Metadata { get; }

        public override IModelMetadataProvider MetadataProvider { get; }

        // Not using a 'real' Stack<> because we want random access to modify the entries.
        public Dictionary<Key, IModelBinder> Collection { get; }

        public override IModelBinder CreateBinder(ModelMetadata metadata)
        {
            var nestedContext = new DefaultModelBinderProviderContext(this, metadata);
            return _factory.CreateBinderCore(nestedContext, token: null);
        }
    }

    [DebuggerDisplay("{ToString(),nq}")]
    private struct Key : IEquatable<Key>
    {
        private readonly ModelMetadata _metadata;
        private readonly object _token; // Explicitly using ReferenceEquality for tokens.

        public Key(ModelMetadata metadata, object token)
        {
            _metadata = metadata;
            _token = token;
        }

        public bool Equals(Key other)
        {
            return _metadata.Equals(other._metadata) && object.ReferenceEquals(_token, other._token);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as Key?;
            return other.HasValue && Equals(other.Value);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return _metadata.GetHashCode() ^ RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(_token);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (_metadata.MetadataKind == ModelMetadataKind.Type)
            {
                return $"{_token} (Type: '{_metadata.ModelType.Name}')";
            }
            else
            {
                return $"{_token} (Property: '{_metadata.ContainerType.Name}.{_metadata.PropertyName}' Type: '{_metadata.ModelType.Name}')";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can register it in the DI container from `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IModelBinderFactory, MyModelBinderFactory>();
```

Comment: Thank you! I've overlooked that issue. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks.You just saved me ! I have been trying to check my code for 2 days now